# Ansible - task from import incorrectly being run when running with tags

Tags: ansible

My `test.yml` playbook looks like this:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: test-role
```

And the `test-role` role looks like this:

```
---
- import_tasks: a.yml
  tags:
    - a

- import_tasks: b.yml
  tags:
    - b
```

but if I run this using:

`ansible-playbook -i inventories/dev --tags "b" playbooks/test.yml --check`

I get tasks from `a.yml` running. 
Why?

FYI, `a.yml` looks like this:

```
- set_fact: test_file="/tmp/test.txt"

- name: Look for the test file
  stat:
      path: "{{ test_file }}"
  register: stat_result

- block:
    - name: If the file exists, end playbook
      debug: msg="Test file existed, ending play"
    - meta: end_play
  when: stat_result.stat.exists == True
```

The error is:

```
ERROR! The conditional check 'stat_result.stat.exists == True' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (stat_result.stat.exists == True): 'stat_result' is undefined
```

and

```
The offending line appears to be:

      debug: msg="Test file existed, ending play"
    - meta: end_play
      ^ here
```

Why is `a.yml` even being run when I'm using tags to specifically not include it?!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tag your top-level playbook if you want to use the command line to include/exclude tags. In your case, the tags need to be in test.yml, not the role.

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: test-role
      tags:
        - a
```

I'm not sure about your setup, but using import_role has always worked well for me:

```
- hosts: vpc
  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: test-role
    tags:
      - a
```

But that may not make a difference for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see tags at the `import_tasks` level here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance